# Issue Running Simple Pinescript Strategy

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to run the ffg. script in tradingview but when I add it to the chart, nothing appears in the strategy tab. The code simply buys when 21SMMA>50SMMA>100SMMA and RSI>50. It closes the trade according to a stop loss and take profit. Here is the script:

```
strategy ("LONG TERM STRAT", overlay = true, initial_capital = 5000, default_qty_value = 5, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
timeStart = timestamp(2018,1,1,0,0)
timeEnd = timestamp(2020,1,1,0,0)
noTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0

// SMOOTHED MOVING AVERAGES
SMMA21= ema(close,42)
SMMA50= ema(close,100)
SMMA100= ema(close,200)

// RSI
RSIval= rsi(close,14)

// LONG CONDITIONS
longCon1 = SMMA21 > SMMA50 and SMMA50 > SMMA100
longCon2 = RSIval > 50

if (longCon1 and longCon2 and noTrade and time>= timeStart and time <= timeEnd )
    stopLoss = low*0.95
    takeProfit = high*1.1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("exit", "long" , stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

Comment: Maybe you need some braces `longCon1 = (SMMA21 > SMMA50) and (SMMA50 > SMMA100)`

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed you have your date end window set to 2020, so we wont see any trades, but there are several more problems you will encounter after that. First we need to move our exit out of the local scope of your entry condition, otherwise it will never be active while we are actually IN a trade! You will see below that I moved that under an if with a positional reference. Next, we need to declare stops and limits globally, otherwise you will get an error if the first introduction of a variable is in the local if of the entry condition. Finally, we need to declare these settings with var. This allows us to "save" our stops/limits and assign them with := under the entry if.

I included some plots for your bracket so you can see :)

Take care and best of luck in your trading and coding!

```
//@version=4
strategy ("LONG TERM STRAT", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100000, default_qty_value = 100000, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
timeStart = timestamp(2018,1,1,0,0)
timeEnd = timestamp(2022,1,1,0,0)
noTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0

// SMOOTHED MOVING AVERAGES
SMMA21= ema(close,42)
SMMA50= ema(close,100)
SMMA100= ema(close,200)

// RSI
RSIval= rsi(close,14)

// LONG CONDITIONS
longCon1 = SMMA21 > SMMA50 and SMMA50 > SMMA100
longCon2 = RSIval > 50

var stopLoss = 0.0
var takeProfit = 0.0
    
if (longCon1 and longCon2 and noTrade and time>= timeStart and time <= timeEnd )
    stopLoss := low*0.95
    takeProfit := high*1.1
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("exit", "long" , stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)

plot (strategy.position_size > 0 ? stopLoss   : na, "Stop Price",   color.red,   style=plot.style_linebr)
plot (strategy.position_size > 0 ? takeProfit : na, "Target Price", color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for these corrections! I am still a bit new to this but I placed the new bit of code into the pine editor and clicked on "add to chart", I recieve no errors but there still is an empty section in strategy tester. Any idea what the issue could be here?

Comment: What timeframe and ticker are you watching?

Comment: also you pasted the code in full?

Comment: I am using the hourly chart on US30 and I have pasted the corrected bit of code in full. I have tried higher timeframes and swapped out to another index but the same issue. In the strategy tester section, it just says "no data" for the specified strategy. Tried loading and running one of the established strategies and those work just fine

Comment: indices generally trade in contracts, or take large capital requirements in real life. Your original code just may have not had enough money. Try setting to contracts in the properties tab, or use the updated code above. I started you out with 100k instead of 5k and you're plotting on US30

Comment: You are welcome Amit! Take care